# Close/Block Port from other Software with Java

Tags: java

We have a Software with reverse shell backdoor.

The Software uses the Port 1337.

How can i prevent that programm from using 1337 by using java?

Comment: So, let me get this straight, you want to build a  firewall to block port 1337. But you dont want to use inbuilt firewall which will be far more secure in blocking that port. Am I correct?

Comment: If the Software needs to bind to this port on startup, it will bind to this port. If you interfere with this, the Software might not start, or might (as suggested below) just move to another port. You need to rethink what you are trying to achieve here, as writing a server socket app in Java is likely not the solution to this problem as described.

Answer (score 0):

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1337);
while(true) {
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    socket.close();
}
```

Read more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket-int-

Comment: This may fail app. Or force it to use another port.

Comment: I have to add that i have to block this port... so i need a Client Server?

Comment: This is not the right way to solve the OPs problem. It merely moves the problem around, and in a terrible way.